# Get group where mean of certain column is max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe that looks like following (10K rows):

> ```
> price distance    cab_type    ride_type   temp    rain    weekend time price_per_km
> 0 9.612   4.54    Lyft    Shared  6.90    0.02    0.0 22:53:00    2.117181  
> 1 2.728   0.63    Uber    Regular 5.09    0.00    0.0 18:38:00    4.330159
> 2 7.512   4.38    Uber    Regular 3.69    0.00    0.0 15:58:00    1.715068
> ```

I need to find the hour when the mean `price_per_km` is highest. I have grouped the data on hour with

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.time.map(lambda t: t.hour))
```

which creates 24 groups for each hour with stats for all the numerical data. I can select max value of mean for price_per_km by

```
max(grouped['price_per_km'].mean())
```

I get the value of maximal mean, but can't figure out how to get in which row it is (for which group it belongs). I can print the group object and find manually in which row it is by `print(grouped.describe())` but that is not efficient and will be very hard with higher number of groups.

So how can I get the group when I know the maximal mean? Note I do not want rows from original DF, I could only find such posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
out = df.groupby(df.time.map(lambda t: t.hour))['price_per_km'].mean().idxmax()
```

Comment: As the note at the end of the post says, I do not want the rows, I want the group number (index), for example 22. Also `s` is undefined, was it meant to be `grouped`?

Comment: @Ruli - It mean `18` in sample data, because `price_per_km` is maximal? There is only one value per `18`, so same like mean in sample data in question.

Comment: my bad, should have shown some more of the sample data, of course on 10K rows the hours repeat, but yes idmax was what I was looking for